# Google Identity Toolkit's generated templates for your website downloads as blank

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

trying to implement google identity toolkit by following the link: https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/configure-service, but I see that "generated templates for your website" available from identity toolkit page downloads as blank document. Why are they blank, am I doing some thing wrong here. Below is the screen print of identity toolkit api page.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must click the "save" button before the templates can be generated.

Comment: I did press save button before generating the template still all 3 comes up blank.

Comment: Have you completed all of these [setup instructions](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/configure-service)? Are you seeing any errors in the javascript console? @SaurabhJuneja